# Spring - How do I avoid returning an entire table and then searching for a single row in java afterwards?

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I want to query the database and return just one single row. Currently I can only return an entire table -
my code for this querying in my DAOImplementation looks like so:

```
SQLMapClientTemplate sqlMap = getSqlClientTemplate();
List<Presidents> presidents = new sqlMap.queryForList("presidents.getAllPresidents");
```

This works fine, however I have another controller method that only needs to return a single president. Currently, I am returning the entire list for this method too and then filtering it inside java to get the individual row i want. This isn't great because I shouldn't have to request an entire table for every simple query.

How do I go about adding some sort of where clause? I don't know why I can't do something along the lines of

```
sqlMap.queryForRow(presidents.getPresidentByName, "Obama");
```

In my President.ibatis.xml file my existing bean select statement is represented as so:

```
 <select id="getALlPresidents" resultMap="Presidents">
    SELECT * FROM president
    </select>
```

Comment: where presidentName="BarackObama";  Is this what you are looking for? I hope not.

Comment: Yes, that's the row I want from my presidents table. This is just practice code for myself, I know it's not well thought out.

Comment: I fail to understand what you are exactly looking for. I hope you find a solution for whatever it is.